# why I can't install netbeans on linux(centos)?

Tags: java, linux, netbeans, centos

I downloaded the [netbeans](http://netbeans.org/downloads/). I followed the Installation Instructions ,but the terminal display the following things:

```
Configuring the installer...
Searching for JVM on the system...
Extracting installation data...

Installer file /home/jiangkai/netbeans-7.2.1-ml-linux.sh seems to be corrupted
```

What's the problems did I confronted with?

I use CentOS(6.3) and installed `jdk7u11`.

Comment: "seems to be corrupted" isnt it clear?

Comment: Your download seems incomplete/broken. You can try to download the netbeans setup again and then try.

Comment: I know the reason. I  download this file on Window .After that ,I upload file via ftp.The file seems become different.So I use sftp(ssh),the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have downloaded the installer on Windows then uploaded via FTP to your Linux machine then I'm pretty sure that the problem is caused by the different line endings that these platforms use.

On Windows, de line endings in text files are the CR/LF pair, while on Linux only a single LF is used for this purpose. Maybe your FTP client was not configured properly to convert the line endings (for example you set the FTP transfer to binary mode).